# Почему не работает ProgressBar

Tags: android, kotlin

У меня в проекте есть имплементация `ProgressDialog` которая считается устаревшей

Как это работает сейчас

Вот сама переменная

```
private val mProgressBar: ProgressDialog by lazy(LazyThreadSafetyMode.NONE) 
{
    ProgressDialog(this)
}
```

Вот так я ей пользуюсь

```
fun setProgressDialog(iShouldShow: Boolean)
{
    when(iShouldShow)
    {
        true ->
        {
            mProgressBar.show()
            AppUtils.isWindowTouchable(window, false)
        }

        false ->
        {
            mProgressBar.dismiss()
            AppUtils.isWindowTouchable(window, true)
        }
    }
}
```

То есть `ProgressDialog` создается динамически

Я хочу сделать тоже самое с `ProgressBar` , мне не нравится идея всовывать его в разметку.

как тут

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3548441/how-to-create-a-progressbar-programmatically

Вот как я это сделал

```
private val mProgressBar: ProgressBar by lazy(LazyThreadSafetyMode.NONE) {
    ProgressBar(this, null, android.R.attr.progressBarStyleSmall)
}

fun setProgressDialog(iShouldShow: Boolean)
{
    when(iShouldShow)
    {
        true ->
        {
            mProgressBar.visibility = View.VISIBLE
            AppUtils.isWindowTouchable(window, false)
        }

        false ->
        {
            mProgressBar.visibility = View.INVISIBLE
            AppUtils.isWindowTouchable(window, true)
        }
    }
}
```

Но это не рабоет

Не пойму почему `ProgressBar` не показывается и нет никаких ошибок.

Comment: Ваш `ProgressBar` создается, но он "нигде", с точки зрения UI. Почитайте какую-нить книжку про работы с UI в Android, такие вопросы отпадут сами собой.

Comment: @EugeneKrivenja я понимаю, что его нужно прицепить к юа как то, но во первых судя по примерам которые я нашел никто никак его никуда не цепляет и все равботает, а второе даже если попробовать его прицепить как показано в ответе ниже, то все равно это не помагает

Comment: Тут азы разжеваны: https://www.journaldev.com/9629/android-progressbar-example

Comment: @EugeneKrivenja то ли я вас не понимаю то ли вы меня... мне нужен прогресБар который я могу создать динамически, я не хочу его всовывать в разметку. Я это указал в вопросе вроде

Comment: Я же вам про азы :) Чтобы вы поняли как это работает. А код или разметка, это вторично. Кстати, из разметки тоже можно динамически UI строить.

Comment: @EugeneKrivenja да азы сами почитайте)) ниче не пойму , что вы хотите сказать. Если хотите ответить на вопрос ответьте. Здесь вопрос не про азы. P.s. чет я не могу пока представить как динамически строить из разметки

Answer (score 0):

Дело в том, что это разные элементы, первый работает как диалог, второй является View(хотя Dialog тоже View). 
Dialog показывается поверх ему не нужно указывать парента, а во втором случае вы создаете переменную, но нигде её не используете.
Как и куда его имплементировать это ваще дело, вот пример который будет работать, дальше я уверен, что вы разберетесь.

```
override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)

    val progressBar: ProgressBar by lazy(LazyThreadSafetyMode.NONE) {
        ProgressBar(this, null, android.R.attr.progressBarStyleSmall)
    }
    setContentView(progressBar)
}
```

Comment: Добавил этот метод `setContentView(progressBar)` в `onCreate()` , но ничего не поменялось

Comment: значит ошибка в вашем коде уберите место, где вы видимость меняете. Поставьте BP в дебаги, добавьте в Watches  ваше прогрессБар, и посмотрите почему он не работает. Если ээто не выявит проблему нуже уже в друго место смотреть, хотя дебаг очень много показывает.

Comment: Не совсем пойму на что нужно смотреть. В дебаге открыть прогресБар у него там штук 100 переменных. куда смотреть там нужно?

Comment: н уже прогресс, значит он создается динамически. Поставьте 2 вотча, один на visible, второй на parent layout. Ну и жмите step